# Does Waterfall Discharge make the water 'cleaner' than surface discharge in a fish tank?

Tags: aquarium, fish

So, My mother is threatening to return the fish tank she got me for my birthday unless I would set the filter to waterfall discharge, I told her I wouldn't as the current is too strong for the type of fish (Betta) I have in the tank - she disagrees even though I read some articles to her.

She claims that the waterfall option will clean the water better and stop cloudiness by showing me a page in an aqua-gardening book that she has that said ***"A Waterfall looks pleasing and will also oxygenate the water for the plants"***.

I have experimented with both modes when I first got it and that the surface discharge is the best for my betta as when I tried waterfall before, my betta kept being 'pushed' back.

Does the waterfall discharge 'clean' the water better than surface discharge?

Comment: what type of filter do you have and how large are your tank,a water fall do have some  negative and some positive effects but some of this depends on your setup.

Comment: Do you have plants? Is the tank "dirty"? If it ain’t broke...

Comment: Waterfalls add oxygen which neither bettas nor plants need. ( I have read that plants may absorb some oxygen when there is no light.)

Comment: @blacksmith37 all fish need oxygen.

Answer (score 2):

Some of the positive effects of a waterfall are:

- A larger amount of water comes in contact with the air, this oxygenates the water better.
- A waterfall will help keeping the surface of the water free from the protein film and dust, and it is nice to look at.

Some of the negative effects are:

- A waterfall will make it harder to keep the temparature stable in your tank due to the larger surface area the water will have. Normally, the temparature in the house is lower than what you want to have in your tank, so it will cool the water.
- A waterfall will increase the evaporation rate from your tank and if the humidity of the air in your house is low, you might lose water from your tank quite fast. (Note: this is positive for the air in your house, but not for the tank as the evaporation will cool it.)
- A waterfall will force CO<sub>2</sub> out of the water and this will make your plants deprived of CO<sub>2</sub> which is one of the essential nutrients - so the plants will grow a lot slower and they will remove less nitrate from the water.
- Betta fish do not need the extra oxygen provided from the waterfall, and as long as the surface of the water is in motion, the water will be saturated with oxygen and the CO<sub>2</sub> will be removed from the water.
- The water will not get any cleaner from a waterfall than it would be from the just below surface outlet from your filter. It is the bacteria in your tank and filter that do the processing of the waste, not the splashing of the water.